# .tsx is not getting converted to .jsx

Tags: typescript

My .tsx file is not getting converted to .jsx and .js

I am using visual studio code. On saving the .tsx file is not getting converted to .jsx file. Do I need to install any plugin for that?

Below is my tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your files are getting converted to `.js` and you want `.jsx` instead, that's because TypeScript is converting the TS code to actual JS code that injects the React nodes as needed. That is because of the

```
"jsx": "react"
```

Property you have on your file.

If you want to preserve the React syntax and have it output the extension as `.jsx`, do

```
"jsx": "preserve"
```

As explained [in the handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html).

Comment: No it is not getting converted to .js too :(